# Access violation error thrown while debugging C++ code

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, linked-list, structure

I am trying to build a parser and store the values in the linked list in C++. I am getting the following error which I am not able to resolve, I looked at other Stack Overflow links but could not find the right answer for it.

I am getting the following error:

> Exception thrown at 0x000000013FCF3954 in parse_and_store.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000018.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

My code for parses_and_store.cpp is given below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <direct.h>

// I don't recommend using the std namespace in production code.
// For ease of reading here.
using namespace std;

struct node {
    string data;
    node *next;
};

// You could also take an existing vector as a parameter.
vector<string> split(string str, char delimiter) {
    vector<string> internal;
    stringstream ss(str); // Turn the string into a stream.
    string tok;

    while (getline(ss, tok, delimiter)) {
        internal.push_back(tok);
    }

    return internal;
}

void printList(node* head)
{
    node *tmp = head;

    while (tmp->next != NULL) {
        tmp = tmp->next;
        cout << tmp->data << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    string myCSV = "one two three four";

    char *buffer = NULL;
    node *n = NULL;

    // Get the current working directory: 
    if ((buffer = _getcwd(NULL, 0)) == NULL)
        perror("_getcwd error");
    else
    {
        //printf("%s \nLength: %d\n", buffer, strlen(buffer));
        printf("%s\n\n", buffer);
        free(buffer);
    }

    std::ifstream file("differential_pair.txt");
    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(file, str))
    {
        // Process str
        cout << str << endl;
        n = new node;
        vector<string> sep = split(str, ' ');
        for (int i = 0; i < sep.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << sep[i] << endl;
            //std::string str(sep[i].begin(), sep[i].end());
            cout << sep.size() << endl;
            std::cin.get();
            n->data = sep[i];
            n = n->next;
        }
    }

    printList(n);

    // If using C++11 (which I recommend)
    /* for(string t : sep)
    *  cout << t << endl;
    */
    file.close();

    std::cout << "\nText verified!" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

My "differential_pair.txt" file contains the following data:

```
VCC 7 0 12
VEE 8 0 -12
VIN 1 0 AC 1
RS1 1 2 1K
RS2 6 0 1K
Q1 3 2 4 MOD1
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: ok i will check with the debugger.

Comment: the debugger just takes me to directly to the "xstring" file where it directs me to the following statement:   if (this->_Myres() < _Newsize)
   _Copy(_Newsize, this->_Mysize()); // reallocate to grow

Comment: Note that requesting urgency is like painting a big downvote target on question - don't do it! It is never urgent for volunteers.

Comment: It looks like you're dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: ok, i will remove the urgency part. and where am i dereferencing an uninitialized pointer? can you please point out!

Comment: adding a small constructor to your node class to initialize member variables would save u some trouble...

Comment: You create a new node `n`, and then in the loop you do `n=n->next` without ever setting `n->next` to a valid value. If you are trying to create a linked list this way, why don't you just use `std::list`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try analyzing the use of `n` in your code.
In the begining of `main` you have `node *n = NULL;` - fine initilized.

Then though a loop for each line you split the elements and try to store it into the list. Look at the commented lines below:

```
while (std::getline(file, str))
{
    // Process str
    cout << str << endl;
    n = new node; // 1
    vector<string> sep = split(str, ' ');
    for (int i = 0; i < sep.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << sep[i] << endl;
        //std::string str(sep[i].begin(), sep[i].end());
        cout << sep.size() << endl;
        std::cin.get();
        n->data = sep[i]; //2
        n = n->next; //3
    }
}
```

For each new line read from file `(1)` you assign new value to `n`. Probably this is not what you want.

In `(2)` you assign the read element from line to the data field which seems fine but then in `(3)` substitute `n` with what is pointed by `n->next`which probably contains garbage.

Afterwards you probably want to print the whole list using `printList(n);` but since `n` has a new value for each line and probably points to not what you expect to, the code fails.

If having a single list for all the elements from the file is what you want, you should treat `n` as the ***head*** element of your list. Also, add an additional variable to point to the current list element (so you won't loose the the list root element).
Inside the inner `for` loop you should create the node elements for each entry

```
for(...){
    //....
    node* entry = new node;
    entry->data = sep[i];
    current->next = entry;
    current = entry;
}
```

Note, you should assure that when the first `node` is created both `n` (treated as head/root) and `current` point to the same data.

So for example before the `while` loop you could put:

```
node* current = new node;
node* n = current;
```

However, this way the first list entry would not contain any data, it would just be used to point to where that data actually starts - which should be handled in the print function. On the other hand you could skip the above and do a check inside the `for` loop like:

```
node* entry = new node;
if (!n)
    n = current = entry;
// ...
```

Which is not pretty nor elegant, since the condition would have been evaluated for each loop iteration and would be `true` only first time but it should do the job.

In general if you don't want to use standard [containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) for your problem you could still try to write a class which internally uses the structure you defined. This way you could hide the unnecessary implementation details: store the head internally, handle cleanup process properly (which is not done at all right now), etc. and make your container easier to use.

Comment: I checked by giving the str="VCC 7 1 2", it is giving access violation for "1" value for "VCC" and "7" it is working fine. it is happening for the third element in the string means "sep[2]" why is it so?

Comment: Even if you fix the `n = n->next` you will still end up with a list containing only last element from the parsed file probably. Since for each parsed line you create entirely new `node` and inside the `for` loop you write to the same `data` element each iteration. Also denote that the `printList(node* head)` expects a head element but you pass `n` which you treat as the last element in your code

Comment: yes i am facing the same problem now, the node has only the last element in it. how to resolve this?

Comment: Just as I've written in the answer, you have to create the `node* entry = new node;` in each loop iteration

Comment: I need multiple linked lists, as in VCC->1->2->3 and second one as VEE->3->2->1 similarly. creating one entry would make only single linkedlist but i need multiple linkedlists.